# Transforming a dataset with crossfilter

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to create a dashboard using dc.js and I want to customize how a data table is visualized. So my data looks something like this

```
agegroup    gender  group   scores  total
  18-24       M      1       0.04    1
  45-54       F      2       2.23    13
  25-34       M      1       0.74    6
  25-34       M      2       1.47    8
  18-24       F      1       2.88    7
  35-44       F      2       3.98    14
```

When I initialize a data table, it'll look the same as my original csv. However what if I want

```
 agegroup    gender  group1.scores   group1.total  group2.scores  group2.total
      18-24       M      0.04              1           0.0               0
      18-24       F      2.88              1           0.0               0
      25-34       M      0.74              8           1.47              8
      25-34       F      0.0               0           0.0               0
```

Here is how I initalize and set up my data table

```
dataTable = dc.dataTable('#data-table');
var tableDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
          return d.gender;
        });
      dataTable
            .width(400)
            .height(800)
            .dimension(tableDim)
              .group(function(d){
                return  "Counts"
              })
              .size(20)
            .columns([
                function(d){
                  return d.gender;},
                function(d){
                  return d.agegroup;
                },
                function(d){
                  return d.group;
                },
                function(d){
                  return d.scores;
                },
                function(d){
                  return d.total;
                }, 
            ])
            .order(d3.ascending)
            .sortBy(function(d){
              return d.gender;
            });
```

I know that crossfilter allows you to filter and subset data quickly but I'm not sure how it'll function transforming datasets. Thanks!

Comment: If possible create a fiddle, it would then be easier for us to get the result you want.

Comment: I would create a fiddle but I don't actually know where to begin or if that functionality is available within crossfilter. What I'm simply trying to do is take a `long-format` dataset and transform it into a `wide-format` dataset. The example that I provided is the best I can do. Any thoughts would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, I was able to do this for now.

```
var tableDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.agegroup;
});

var dataTable = dc.dataTable("#someTable");
dataTable.width(300).height(800)
    .dimension(tableDim)
    .group(function (d) {
    return "Counts";
})
    .columns([
function (d) {
    return d.agegroup;
},
function (d) {
    return d.gender;
},
function (d) {
    if (d.group == 1) return d.scores;
    else return 0;
},
function (d) {
    if (d.group == 1) return d.total;
    else return 0;
},
function (d) {
    if (d.group == 2) return d.scores;
    else return 0;
},
function (d) {
    if (d.group == 2) return d.total;
    else return 0;
}]);

dc.renderAll();
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iSudeep/458hyftb/) working with the above code. Use this or make a new one next time when you are asking for such solutions on SO.

Remember, using `dc.dataTable` you may not be able to reduce the number of rows in the data set. If you really want to reduce the number of rows you may try `group().reduce()` methods and create new fields for group1.total, group1.scores etc..

Comment: Welcome, actually I took more time to set up Fiddle for your question than just to get the table as needed.

Comment: Well I tried to use the `reduce()` and `group()` functions in dc.js to remove the number of rows but I'm having no luck. Can you [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275308/dc-js-reducing-rows-in-data-table/31275725#31275725)?